# Make an Apple give you Experience?? | Minecraft Forge Modding 1.7.10

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Hello people of the internet, I would like to know if there was a way to make a custom food item give you XP. I am in the middle of making a mod and would like "SimonApple" To give me XP. Please let me know if there is a way to do this.

```
package com.notsimon.blocksplus;

import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLPostInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;
import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.material.MapColor;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;
import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemFood;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;

@Mod(modid = "ep", name = "Experience Plus", version = "1.0")
public class ExperiencePlus {

    public static Item SimonApple;
    public static Item MagentaDust;
    public static Block MagentaOre;
    public static Block MagentaBlock;

    @EventHandler
    public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event) {
        //Item/Block init and registering
        //Config handling
        //X * 0.5 = 20 Hunger
        SimonApple = new ItemFood(10, 0.5F, false).setUnlocalizedName("SimonApple").setTextureName("bp:SimonApple").setCreativeTab(tabBlocksPlus);
        MagentaOre = new BlockTable(Material.iron).setBlockName("MagentaOre").setBlockTextureName("bp:MagentaOre").setCreativeTab(tabBlocksPlus);
        MagentaDust = new ItemTable().setUnlocalizedName("MagentaDust").setTextureName("bp:MagentaDust").setCreativeTab(tabBlocksPlus);
        MagentaBlock = new MagentaBlock(Material.iron).setBlockName("MagentaBlock").setBlockTextureName("bp:MagentaBlock").setCreativeTab(tabBlocksPlus);
        //item.itemTable and substring(5) removes "item."
        GameRegistry.registerItem(SimonApple, SimonApple.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
        GameRegistry.registerBlock(MagentaOre, MagentaOre.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
        GameRegistry.registerItem(MagentaDust, MagentaDust.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
        GameRegistry.registerBlock(MagentaBlock, MagentaBlock.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
        GameRegistry.registerWorldGenerator(new OreGeneration(), 0);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event) {
        //Proxy, TileEntity, entity, GUI and Packet Registering
        GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(SimonApple, 2), new Object[]{"MMM","MBM","MMM", 'M', ExperiencePlus.MagentaDust, 'B', ExperiencePlus.MagentaBlock});
        GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(MagentaBlock), new Object[] {"MMM", "MMM", "MMM",'M', ExperiencePlus.MagentaDust});
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void postInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent event) {

    }

    public static CreativeTabs tabBlocksPlus = new CreativeTabs("tabBlocksPlus"){
        @Override
        public Item getTabIconItem() {
            return new ItemStack(MagentaOre).getItem();
        }
    };




}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit the current apple item in the game, you would have to create your own one as a forge mod item, which seems like what oyu have done. To make an item give XP, you use this:

`player.addExperienceLevel(1); //player is an EntityPlayer or an EntityPlayerMP`

### SimonApple Item Class

This is what the item class for the SimonApple would look like (without imports):

```
public class SimonApple extends ItemFood {
    private static final int LevelsToAdd = 10; //just an example number; play around with it

    public SimonApple(String unlocalizedName, int healAmount, float saturationModifier, boolean wolvesFavorite, CreativeTab creativeTab) {
        super(healAmount, saturationModifier, wolvesFavorite);
        this.setUnlocalizedName(unlocalizedName);
        this.setTextureName(Main.MODID + ":" + unlocalizedName);
        this.setCreativeTab(creativeTab);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFoodEaten(ItemStack stack, World world, EntityPlayer player) {
        super.onFoodEaten(stack, world, player);
        player.addExperienceLevel(LevelsToAdd);
    }
}
```

### Changing Variables in the ExperiencePlus Class

You would need to change this:

```
public static Item SimonApple;
```

To something around the lines of this:

```
public static Item simonApple;
```

And you would need to change this:

```
SimonApple = new ItemFood(10, 0.5F, false).setUnlocalizedName("SimonApple").setTextureName("bp:SimonApple").setCreativeTab(tabBlocksPlus);
```

To just this:

```
simonApple = new SimonApple("SimonApple", 10, .5f, false, tabBlocksPlus);
```

***NOTE:*** 10 should be the heal amount, and .5f should be the saturation amount (see table [here](http://pastebin.com/hxqqFHzB))

Answer (score 1):

Either create a new item as Abob78 suggests, or create an eventHandler that subscribes to the [PlayerUseItem](http://www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/Event_Reference#PlayerUseItemEvent) event to be triggered at the Finish state.

To limit the items that that trigger it, you'll have to look at using the itemstack [NBT data](http://www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/Creating_NBT_for_items) to store a flag to identify "simon apples" from regular apples. this can be something as simple as a boolean flag such as "isSimonApple"

From the event, you should be able to extract an [EntityLiving](http://takahikokawasaki.github.io/minecraft-resources/javadoc/forge/1.8-11.14.1.1320/net/minecraft/entity/EntityLiving.html) reference that can be cast to a [player reference](http://takahikokawasaki.github.io/minecraft-resources/javadoc/forge/1.8-11.14.1.1320/net/minecraft/entity/player/EntityPlayer.html).
Then either augment the triggering player's XP or spawn XP orbs at their location.